# insufficient_scope unable to post to a page as an admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app currently in Development (the status of the app) in which I am an Admin on and I have two Pages, which I am also an Admin on.  My understanding is that when in development, if you're an admin on a page you're able to post to that page.

I've gone through the oAuth flow and have received an `access_token`.  I have the following permissions:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "email",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "manage_pages",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_show_list",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "publish_pages",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I try to post to a particular page I'm an Admin on using `${PAGE_ID}/feed`, I receive the following:

> (#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and
>   app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as
>   an admin with sufficient administrative permission"

Any idea what could be causing this or if there's some "weird" setting I may have overlooked?  Thank you!

Comment: When do you get the error?

Comment: When I try to post to the feed of the page.  I'm posting to `PAGE_ID/feed` with the user's `access_code` and `message`

Comment: You have to use a page access token

Comment: @WizKid That was it :/ - thank you!